# jQuery datepicker post to php switch to redirect page

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker, switch-statement

I may be completely overdoing this, but could someone explain what have I done wrong?

jQuery:

```
onSelect: function(){
            $.post("nav.php",function(){
                $.datepicker.parseDate("Md");
            });
            },
```

php:

```
<?
$d=date("Md")
    switch ($d) {
        case Jan1:
            header(Location: '/html/Jan/Jan1/Jan1.html')
        case Jan2:
            header(Location: '/html/Jan/Jan2/Jan2.html')
    }
?>
```

As you might suspect, my goal is to get the `datepicker` to redirect to a page when a certain date is chosen, where I have set up a `php switch` to handle that (there will be a ton of pages, so I thought that would be pretty much the cleanest way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to jedwards, he gave me the right push.

Here's a bit modified code (the original wasn't working).

```
onSelect: function(){
            var getd = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
            var datePart = $.datepicker.formatDate("M/Md/Md",getd);
            location.href = ("/html/" + datePart + ".html");
        },
```

Comment: Happy you got it working, feel free to check your own answer instead, especially if you'll be hanging around SO :-)

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a need for PHP here.  Something like

```
onSelect: function(dateStr, dp){
    var datePart = $.datepicker.formatDate("M/Md/Md", dp.getDate());
    window.location("http://www.yoursite.com/" + datePart + ".html"
    },
```

Is probably closer to what you want.

The idea is to get the date using the [`getDate()`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#method-getDate) method, then format it in the `Jan/Jan1/Jan1` style, then redirect your browser to the page you want.

You'll have to change a few things in this to get it to work for sure, but this should point you in the right direction.